# What is the difference between hh and HH in dateformatting in SQL?

Tags: sql

When formatting my time i get different results depending on the use of hh or HH.

Can someone tell me why this happens?
The problem occurs with the following code, returning a NULL on the 2nd result.

```
declare @TIMEPART time = getdate()

declare @datetime datetime2(7) = getdate()

select format(@timepart, 'hh\:mm'), format(@timepart, 'HH\:mm'), format(@datetime, 'hh\:mm'), format(@datetime, 'HH\:mm')
```

Comment: In C# so assume on SQL too, HH is for 24 hour format, whereas hh is 12 hour format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HH:mm format is not a valid conversion for the time datatype and for the format(time, time format) function it is not the correct syntax. Because of this the format function returns a null. HH:mm is the conversion type for 24 hour clock for datetime datatypes but is not compatible with the time datatype as the time datatype is already in the 24 hour clock format(not sure why this is the case but I think it is because the time datatype can do more than just represent 24h clock time).  The AM\PM format type hh:mm is only valid with the datetime datatypes and for time it will just return the 24 hour time since this is all a time datatype can return. You would have to convert the time to a datetime if the input value datatype is time in order to display the AM/PM format as I have shown below.

```
    declare @TIMEPART time = '21:20:20.0570000'

    declare @datetime datetime2(7) = '21:20:20.0570000'



    select format(@timepart, 'hh\:mm'), format(convert(datetime,@timepart), 'hh:mm'), format(@datetime, 'hh\:mm'), format(@datetime, 'HH\:mm')
```

If you still want the data type of the second column to be time then you would have to convert back to time

```
    cast(format(convert(datetime,@timepart), 'hh:mm') as time)
```

However in this example the time would be 9:20 AM and not 9:20 PM since time is only stored as a 0 to 23 value for the hour.  This is a good example of why is is advisable to always try to return any time value in the 0-23 hour format.  If you do need to display the time in the 12 hour format you are better off converting it to a varchar.

```
    convert(varchar(15), format(convert(datetime,@timepart), 'hh:mm'))
```

One other thing to note is that for datetimes the \ in the format is not needed, for example

```
format(@datetime, 'hh\:mm')
```

and

```
format(@datetime, 'hh:mm')
```

will return the same value.  However the \ is needed for time datatype functions.

```
format(@timepart, 'hh\:mm')
```

will return a hh:mm time but

```
format(@timepart, 'hh:mm')
```

will return null